# How to generate substrings of a dot-separated string?

Tags: python

I am struggling to generate a list of `substrings` from a given list of strings.

I have a list of domains -

```
domains = ["abc.pqr.com", "pqr.yum.abc.com"]
```

Now, for each domain in the list I want to generate subdomains.

For example the subdomains of domain `"abc.pqr.com"` would be

```
["pqr.com", "abc.pqr.com"]
```

Also, for domain `"pqr.yum.abc.com"` the subdomains would be

```
["yum.abc.com", "pqr.yum.abc.com", "abc.com"]
```

So the out put of the method would be -

```
["yum.abc.com", "pqr.yum.abc.com", "abc.com", "pqr.com", "abc.pqr.com"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to iterate on elements then split your element by the '.' seperator. After that in order to keep the 'com' element intact, we iterate on the range - 1. After creating every alternative, we join the result again with the seperator "."

```
domains = ["abc.pqr.com", "pqr.yum.abc.com"]
domains_new = []
for d in domains:
    liste = d.split(".")
    for i in range(len(liste)-1):
        domains_new.append(liste[i:])
domains_new = [".".join(ele) for ele in domains_new]
domains_new
```

output:

```
['abc.pqr.com', 'pqr.com', 'pqr.yum.abc.com', 'yum.abc.com', 'abc.com']
```

Comment: never hurts to have a more robust check for the pivot point. These solutions assume the pivot point to be "com" and assume that it is always the last one. You might want to take it from a list like [com, co, org, net] and then to allow a location to be behind this pivot such that "com.ca" can be preserved as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the domains only contain simple tlds like `.com` and no second-level domains like `.co.uk`, you can use a python list comprehension.

```py
[domain.split(".", x)[-1] for domain in domains for x in range(domain.count("."))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
domains = ["abc.pqr.com", "pqr.yum.abc.com"]
lst = []
for i in domains:
    splits = i.split('.')
    for j in range(len(splits),1,-1):
        lst.append('.'.join(splits[-j:]))
```

I did something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/users/12959241/alphabetagamma